# Unable to update/delete/truncate table with foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id1 int(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(20)
);    

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    newid int(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    f_id int(10)
);
```

Now, I have added a foreign key constrain

```
ALTER TABLE table2 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY (f_id) REFERENCES table1 (id)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Now, the problem is I am unable to update/delete/truncate the table 'table2'. What is the exact problem here and how to solve it?

Comment: Define 'unable' with an error message, reproducible scenario or something.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key enforces referential integrity,try to remove the record from table 1 and then table 2. You cannot truncate a table which is having FK

Comment: Table1 is the **referenced** table, deleting from it requires no records in table2 referencing to the id in table1 or proper on delete option.

Comment: can I update a record in table2 ? If no,what changes should i make so that I can update the records of table2?

Comment: @Hari With the information you've provided in the question, we have no idea. You've posted a few DDLs, full of syntax errors, a scenario and no error message/example data and query to reproduce your problem. Yes, you should be able update the record if you don't want to update the referencing column to a non-existing value.

Comment: if t1 is the referenced, and t2 is the referencing, then you cannot truncate t1, but can possibly delete from it. You can truncate t2 no problem, and you can delete from it no problem.

Comment: As for updating t2, that is no problem, unless the update violates ref integrity.